# How do I solve this question?

Tags: transient, mesh-analysis

In the given figure, the steady state is reached with the switch open. At t = 0, the switch is closed.
Find Vc(t) for t > 0.

[image: Figure]

How do I proceed solving this question?
So far, I've tried applying KVL in both the meshes, and solved them simultaneously, but I'm getting incorrect answer.

Comment: Please add the steps that you have followed already, into the question. Use the small [edit] button below the question to add the details.

Comment: First, tell us the steady state solution you have found for \$t<0\$. Then tell us the KVL equations you have used for \$t>0\$. Please mark the reference directions of currents and voltages in the image itself before writing the KVL equations.

Comment: What is Thev voltage and R at switch node (to left)